# Open popup conditional from controler MVC And Retrieve the answer

Tags: asp.net-mvc, controller, modal-dialog

I want from my controller open a poup-up that contains data and ask a question to the user. According to his answer, I continue or stop treatment.

```
Function Traitement(model As TraitementViewModel, confirm_value As String) As ActionResult
    Try
        If (ModelState.IsValid) Then
            Dim exception As Exception = Nothing
            Dim mois As Integer = Mid(model.dateTraitement, 4, 2)
            Dim annee As Integer = Right(model.dateTraitement, 4)
            Session("mois") = mois
            Session("annee") = annee
            Dim extract As Extraction = New Extraction()

            Dim result As Integer = extract.Recherche(mois, annee).Rows.Count()
            If (result <> 0) Then
                OPEN POPUP

                   Artciles    Montant
                        1       100
                        2       200

                   Do you want continue

                         YES  NO



                  IF(confirm_value = "yes") Then
                   continue...
                  Else
                   Exit Function
            Else
                continue...
            End If


        End If

End Function
```

Comment: Please read [Under what circumstances may I add “urgent” or other similar phrases to my question, in order to obtain faster answers?](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/q/326569) - the summary is that this is not an ideal way to address volunteers, and is probably counterproductive to obtaining answers. Please refrain from adding this to your questions.

Comment: thanks for the advice